# Run Firefox on ubuntu 14.04 automatically when it starts up

Tags: firefox

How do I make Firefox run automatically when Ubuntu statrts up? I'm using version 14.04

Answer (score 5):

To start Firefox up when your session commences use the following steps:

1. Use the [Dash](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/unity-dash-intro.html) to find and open Startup Applications
2. Click 'Add' and enter the command `firefox` in the Command field and confirm with 'Add'

**Reference:**

- [Startup Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html)

Comment: Hmmm I Done all of that. It still does not launch when I restart Ubuntu.  Is there any other way?

Comment: Perhaps your copy of Firefox is not installed in your $PATH, which would be unusual. Try using the 'Browse' button to manually locate Firefox...